# How can I customise proximity zones for ibeacons using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

How can I set my own radius limits for Immediate, Near and Far zones when I range ibeacons using CoreLocation?

Comment: You can't. The `proximity` property gives you an indication of the beacon's proximity but you can't get a precise distance due to the nature of the RF environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot configure Proximity thresholds, it is easy enough to do roll your own based on the `accuracy` field, which is effectively a distance estimate in meters:

```
if beacon.accuracy < 0 {
  // unknown
}
else if beacon.accuracy < 0.5 {
  // immediate
}
else if beacon.accuracy < 3.0 {
  // near
}
else {
  // far
}
```

The values above approximate CoreLocation's default behavior, but you can alter them to suit your needs.